# process returned 255 (0xff) code blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I don't know where my problem is. I tried to compile the code once and it worked. However, I copied it in a new project in order to modify it, just the colour or the time to wait, and it just works in the first programme.
What is wrong? I feel really frustrated. 
With this code I want to graphic the sine function.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
# include <SDL.h>
# include <math.h>
# define PI 3.141592
# define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
# define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

int main(int argc, char **argv){

   int x,y;

   double fx,angulo;

//   Uint8* posicion;

   Uint32 color;

   SDL_Window*win = SDL_CreateWindow("y=sin(x)", 100,100, 640, 480, 0);


//   SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_INFORMATION,"info", "Window      creada",win);

   SDL_Renderer*ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1,   SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED    |     SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

  /* Create surface */

  SDL_Surface*surface =   SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,32,0,0,0);


  //get the pixels

  Uint32*pixels = (Uint32*)surface-> pixels;


  /* Lock the surface */

  SDL_LockSurface(surface);


   color = SDL_MapRGB(surface-> format, 255, 0, 0);

   for(x=0;x<360;x++){

      angulo=x*PI/180;

      fx=240+50*sin(angulo);

      y=round(fx);

       pixels[ ( y* surface-> w ) + x ] = color;

     }

    /* Unlock the surface */

    SDL_UnlockSurface(surface);


    //imprescindible

   SDL_Texture *tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, surface);

   SDL_RenderCopy(ren,tex,NULL,NULL);

   SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

   SDL_Delay(1000);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: So, what exactly doesn´t work?

Comment: Which IDE and version are you using and what platform and architect is your machine?

Comment: it just appears "code.exe stopped working" and then "process returned 255 (0xff) code blocks"

Comment: @MaríaMR Your code contains no checking to see if those functions return errors.  You can't just assume things will work -- you have to check the return values for the functions you're calling.  For example, here is the `SDL_CreateWindow` documentation.  Please read what the return value denotes and how to get further error information:  https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow

Comment: I am working in win7 64bit and I am working in VS2013. I have set up my Solution to the appropriate include directories for both the include files and static libs, I also copied the *dll file into my projects directory where the executable is being generated. I am able to successfully compile and build, however when I run this. I am getting a crash on this line of code: Uint32* pixels = (Uint32*)surface->pixels; I am getting an unhandled exception an access violation. And in my debugger the pointer to surface is NULL or empty! When I stepped through SDL_CreateRGBSurface(...) is returning null!

Comment: Use the debugger to see which line the problem is happening on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing with your source code I modified it a little bit and this is what I came up with and I got it to compile and run returning no errors from exiting main(). Just make sure that your current project or solution is pointing to the appropriate include files for both the include directories and static library files for this SDL library and also make sure that you have the dll in the same directory as your executable is located for this project. Also make sure that you are using the appropriate build to either it be for x86 or 64bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <math.h>

const float PI 3.141592;
const int SCREEN_WIDTH 640
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    double fx = 0;
    double angulo = 0;
    Uint32 color = 0;

    SDL_Window* win = nullptr;
    win = SDL_CreateWindow( "y=sin(x)", 100, 100, 640, 480, 0);

    SDL_Renderer* ren = nullptr;
    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer( win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );

    SDL_Surface* surface = nullptr;
    surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

    Uint32* pixels = nullptr;
    pixels = static_cast<Uint32*>( surface->pixels );

    SDL_LockSurface(surface);
    color = SDL_MapRGB( surface-> format, 255, 0, 0 );
    for( x=0; x<360; x++ ){
        angulo = x * PI / 180;
        fx = 240 + 50 * sin( angulo );
        y = static_cast<int>( round( fx ) );
        pixels[ ( y* surface-> w ) + x ] = color;
    }
        SDL_UnlockSurface( surface );

        SDL_Texture *tex = nullptr;
        tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( ren, surface );

        SDL_RenderCopy( ren, tex, NULL, NULL );
        SDL_RenderPresent( ren );
        SDL_Delay( 1000 );

        return 0;
}
```

There was only a couple of changes I have made, The First is I prefer to use const values for globals as opposed to #DEFINES. The second is any variable that is declared I initialize them all to a valid 0 or null state. I if you do not have the option of using nullptr for pointers you can still use 0 or NULL but nullptr is preferred! This way all of your pointers are not set or pointing to anything in memory.

The second change I made were the few casting calls you had!  Instead of doing this:

```
int someInt = 10;
float someFloat = 0.0f;
someInt += (int)someFloat;
```

I do this instead:

```
someInt += static_cast<int>( someFloat );
```

If you do not have the option of using static_cast<>(), dynamic_cast<>(), reinterprest_cast<>() then you can continue to cast from one data type to another in the way you are doing. I like the method of casting I chose to use for two reasons, one it is safer and cleaner code for reading, and the other the user and even yourself when you go back to it can easily see which type casting you are using!

As for your bug in the code it wasn't until I set all of the pointers you were declaring to a nullptr first before calling the appropriate functions and in your 
SDL_CreateRGBSurface() call you have:

```
 ... = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0 );
```

This should be:

```
... = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
```

What was happening is you were setting your Bit Depth to 0, then your R color mask to 32 which for an int is not defined properly since the BitMasks use hex values and not interger or unsigned values.

Here is a link to the documentation on this function: [SDL::CreateRGBSurface](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29)

As for being able to successfully compile, link and build that depends on your OS, IDE and how you have your project / solution settings configured for this library!

I hope this helps you! :)

Comment: you are amazing! I'm extremely grateful for your help!!!!! Now I understand what you mean and I'll put it into practice in my next codes :D

Comment: You are very welcome! The best part is I have no formal training or any college credits in programming, computer science or software engineering. Everything I have learned is self taught through research, trial and error. Since my passion or desire is in 3D graphics rendering, animations and Game Engine development my choice of preferred language is C++ which is one of the hardest languages to master other then assembly itself. I would say that I am at an advanced intermediate level. There is still much that I can learn. This is why I like to help others for it strengthens my own skills.

Comment: really? have you learnt everything on your own? awesome¡

Comment: There are many tutorials online most of text based, some are video, some are free many you have to subscribe to. I first started to learn the C++ language around 2005 and it wasn't until around 2008 - 09 that I was beginning to tackle the more advanced concepts such as polymorphism and templates. Doing basic logic, arithmetic code is easy, but getting into parsing and memory management takes time and patience, especially when some of your Compiler error messages seem cryptic. Just keep at it and you will do just fine! :)